# NSSharingService by Facebook in Mac app with no account configured

Tags: facebook, macos, twitter, social-networking, sharing

I am trying to share a link in an Mac App in Facebook/twitter and I would like to check if the user has the account in settings. If the account is not in settings, I would like to do this sharing by web browser.

I try the following code, because [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) said that you can check if the account is configured using canPerformWithItems with the nil parameter. (facebookSharingService is NSSharingService)

```
  NSMutableArray *shareItems = [self prepareItemsToMessage];

    if ([self.facebookSharingService canPerformWithItems:nil])
    {
        /*
         Perform the service using the array of items.
         */
        [self.facebookSharingService performWithItems:shareItems];
    }
    else
    {
        [self shareFacebookByWebBrowser];
    }
```

Using this code, pop up appears saying that I need to configure the account. How can I check if the account of Facebook or Twitter in in Settings or not?